# Evaluate trigonometric function

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, evaluation, trigonometry

Can anyone help me to evaluate the trigonometric function below?

 Please look that the picture for more details.

Here is the code to evaluate:

```
ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k]
```

From trigonometry we know that $tan^{-1}(k)+tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{k})=\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, when I put input that expression into Mathematica I get this:

$$ArcTan[\frac{1}{k}]+ArcTan[k]$$

Can anyone help me to get the result of $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The identity does not hold for negative values of `k`.

Comment: So let's assume that k is positive, how to add that condition and simplify to the result of pi/2?

Comment: I tried `FullSimplify[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k], k > 0]` but it did not work.  I am still looking at this.

Comment: I've got only that `FullSimplify[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k] == Pi/2, k > 0]` yields `True`; but `ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k] /. k -> 137 // FullSimplify` (or with any other `k`) gives `Pi/2` (or `1.5708` if `k` is inexact).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We know that `FullSimplify[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k], k > 0]` does not do it. But by first converting to exponentials, now Mathematica does it

```
   FullSimplify[ TrigToExp[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k]] , k > 0]
```

Gives as output $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
Assuming[k > 0, 
 Solve[FullSimplify[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k] == x], x]]

(* ==> {{x -> Pi/2}} *)
```

Here, I equate the expression in the question to a symbol `x` and ask *Mathematica* what `x` is. Inserting an apparently trivial [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) sometimes leads to further simplifications.

In this case, the simplification already occurs in the inner step:

```
Assuming[k > 0, FullSimplify[ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k] == x]]

(* ==> 2 x == Pi *)
```

But `Solve` makes sure that you're getting the result with `x` on one side of the equation.

**Edit: Making it work purely with `Simplify`:**

This is the shortest method I could find:

```
1/FullSimplify[1/(ArcTan[k] + ArcTan[1/k]), k > 0]

(* ==> Pi/2 *)
```

So here I just added the operation `1/...` to get `FullSimplify` to do what I want. Then I undo the inverse after the simplification.

Comment: Really interesting, what is operation 1/...? I couldn't find it from Wolfram Documentation.

Comment: I just meant the operation of taking the inverse: `1/(ArcTan...)` - didn't want to repeat the code. It's not meant to be a secret command with three dots. Although I don't blame you for suspecting as much in a language like *Mathematica*.

Comment: Well,  I knew what you meant by three dots but I didn't notice the inverse inside FullSimplify function so I thought 1/... is as a magic command!